# Iterate over a list and replace values with an index

Tags: python

I have a list that is the result of a string `.split`.

E.g. for the string `numbers = "1/2//4//6"`:

```py
>>> numbers = numbers.split("/")
['1', '2', '', '4', '', '5']
```

I'd like to create a list based on that where any empty values (i.e `''`) are replaced with a number that increments only with empty values. So the end result should be:

```py
[1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6]
```

The first empty value has been replaced with `1` and the second with `2`.

I've created a loop that can do this, but frankly, it's an eyesore and takes me back to Java:

```py
auto = 1
for i,number in enumerate(numbers):
    if number == "":
        numbers[i] = auto
        auto += 1
    else:
        numbers[i] = int(number)
```

I'd love to be able to do this without using an external variable and, ideally, via a list comprehension instead.

Is this possible in Python?

Comment: `c = itertools.count(1)` will also create "an external variable"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `itertools.count`:

```
import itertools
c = itertools.count(1)
numbers =  "1/2//4//6"
result = [int(i) if i else next(c) for i in numbers.split('/')]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6]
```

Edit: if you wish to avoid "external" variables related to the incrementation process, and if you are willing to store the split results of numbers, you can use `enumerate`. However, it is *not* as efficient nor as clean as using `itertools.count`:

```
numbers = "1/2//4//6".split('/')
result = [int(a) if a else sum(not c for c in numbers[:i])+1 for i, a in enumerate(numbers)]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6]
```